# How to center an `itemize` in beamer, together with its headline?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, lists, itemize

I failed to center an `itemize` in beamer, together with its headline. In my second try below, although the `items` are centered, their headline (i.e. the text `My second try: Centering the itemize`) is not left-aligned with them.

> How to center an `itemize` in beamer, together with its headline?

[image: centering-itemize]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Centering the itemize}
  My first try: Centering the itemize
  \begin{center}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item item1
      \item item2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{center}

  \begin{center}
  My second try: Centering the itemize
  \begin{itemize}
    \centering
    \item item1
    \item item2
  \end{itemize}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is one way; using a `tabular`-like structure:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{%
  \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}\hspace*{\labelsep}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Centering the itemize}
  My first try: Centering the itemize
  \begin{itemize}
    \item item1
    \item item2
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
      My second try: Centering the itemize \\
      \tabitem item1 \\
      \tabitem item2
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You insert an "`\item`" inside the `tabular` using `\tabitem`.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, what does `@{}l@{}` in `tabular` mean? (I can understand something like `|c|l|`.)

Comment: @hengxin: `@{}` removes the column spacing.

Answer (score 11):

Another way is to include the itemize list within the minipage environment and center the minipage. The key is to make the width of the minipage just enough to hold the widest item in the list. I use trial and error, but I am sure there is a cleverer way.

[image: LaTeX output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Centering the itemize}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{0.14\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item item1
        \item item2
      \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is another way:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item  \begin{center} item1 \end{center}
    \item  \begin{center} item2 \end{center}
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: This doesn't center any headline

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\linewidth}
     \begin{itemize}
       \item Item 1
       \item Item 2
       \item  Item 3
     \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  In what is your answer different from @Mark Sprague answer?