# How do I center a bullet/numbered/description list horizontally?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, itemize, description, center

Say I want the `description` environment in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Some text\\
some more
\begin{center}
center
\end{center}
\begin{description}
  \item[desc1] text1
  \item[desc2] text2 text2
  \item[desc3] text3 text3 text3
\end{description}
other text
\end{document}
```

do be horizontally centered, as a whole, i.e. the longest item should be horizontally centered in the page. Clearly, if one of the entries is longer than `\textwidth`, then it would be back the original position.

Enclosing it in the `center` environment doesn't seem to work.

I thought `\hfill` would come handy, but I haven't managed to write a solution using it.

I guess another strategy could consist in computing the width of the environment being typeset, and using that as the width of an enclosing `minipage`, or something.

---

I see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238846/how-to-center-an-itemize-in-beamer-together-with-its-headline) using `tabular` as an alternative is proposed, but I was looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Hi, can you please post a compilable snippet? And specify what you mean by "horizontally centered": each line on its own? The whole block? What if any line is longer than the line width?

Comment: @Rmano, better now?

Comment: Much better now, thanks. The problem with center is that `description` generate full lines... thinking about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the `description` in a `varwidth`-box (which produces a `minpage` and calculates it's width):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
Some text\\
some more
\begin{center}
center
\end{center}

\begin{center}
  \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
    \begin{description}
      \item[desc1] text1
      \item[desc2] text2 text2
      \item[desc3] text3 text3 text3
    \end{description}
  \end{varwidth}
\end{center}

other text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd say perfect. I'll wait a bit more before accepting, in order to see another answer that probably Rmano is gonna add. +1 in the meanwhile

Comment: @Enlico no, I won't add anything, this is a very nice answer!